# Universe inconsistency as an effect

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, universe, termination, side-effects

The Internet tells me there is some work on languages that permit general recursion but carry information about possible divergence in the type system.  For instance, the simply-typed language [Koka](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/paper-20.pdf) and the dependently-typed language [F-star](https://www.fstar-lang.org/papers/mumon/) appear to have a built-in primitive "divergence" effect whose presence is inferred by termination-checking.

From a logical perspective, general recursion leads to inconsistency by allowing the definition of non-terminating programs of type $\bot$, so unrestricted general recursion is unacceptable in a proof assistant.  But marking general recursion by a divergence effect in the type system ought to restore logical consistency in the pure fragment.  (Of course, in a dependent type theory one also has to decide to what extent types can depend on possibly nonterminating computations, and hence whether the latter may be executed during typechecking.)

Aside from explicit general recursion, non-termination and hence logical inconsistency can also be derived from universe inconsistencies such as $\rm Type:Type$.  Has anyone ever considered a dependent type theory / programming language in which universe inconsistencies are permitted but similarly guarded by a built-in effect?

Comment: I was told that linearity can forbit the construction of Girard paradox but I'm not so sure

Comment: Linearity prevents most "Russel-like" paradoxes, e.g. the linear set theory with unrestricted comprehension: http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~terui/lastfin.pdf

Comment: I'm actually having trouble imagining a "universe guarded" type theory that does not look very much like normal MLTT with universes. Is it possible that the answer is "this is already what we're doing"?

Comment: @cody I'm imagining a type theory in which one could write Girard's paradox as a proof of $\bot ! \mathsf{univ}$, indicating a contradiction involving the effect of universe inconsistency, just as one might have by general recursion a proof of $\bot ! \mathsf{div}$ indicating a contradiction involving the effect of divergence.  In normal MLTT with universes, Girard's paradox cannot be given any type.

Comment: How would this be different from a reader monad similar to the propositional resizing axiom, but sans the restriction to propositions?

Comment: Could you just define a Universe ala Tarski using induction-recursion, and then have it refer to itself using general recursion as an effect? Something like the guarded modality. Then you would be able to express Type:Type with the same effect as non-termination

Comment: @Trebor I'm not entirely clear what you mean: as far as I know, propositional resizing is an axiom, not an effect.  If you have a specific proposal, you could write it in an answer.  But I was really asking about a published reference.

Comment: @JoeyEremondi Well, a inductive-recursive universe defined inside the theory is not the same as the ambient universe specified in the type theory.  And when I tried to do what you suggest just now in Agda, what complained was not the termination checker but the positivity checker.  Can non-positivity of a datatype also be regarded as some kind of effect?

Comment: A reader monad can be regarded as an effect, and assuming an axiom is exactly using the reader monad.

Comment: Is the motivation to be able to write handlers that allow for local "safe" usage of Type : Type? I have no suggestions, just curious.

Comment: @Trebor Hmm... so you're imagining a reader monad for an axiom of the form $\prod_{i:Level} \prod_{A:Type_{i+1}} \sum_{B:Type_i} \uparrow B = A$, so a form of "propositional type-in-type"?  That's not exactly what I was envisioning, but I can see how it could achieve something of the same thing.

Comment: @MikeShulman yes, non-positivity can be modeled as an effect, look up Guarded Type Theory, Topos of Trees, Guarded Cubical Agda, etc. The idea is that if you can make a universe ala Tarski, you can use that to give a (syntactic) model for a type theory that has Type:Type natively.

Comment: @JoeyEremondi Sorry, I don't follow.  Can you explain, or point me to an explanation, of how guarded type theory models non-positivity as an effect?

Comment: The only issues with type:type and with non positive data are potential nonterminatation.  I don't see why you couldn't handle them the same way you would handle nontermination from general recursion.  I don't think anyone has implemented it yet.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have an answer, but I would like to provide some buzzwords and references that will make it easier to find relevant literature.

##### Some background information

Computational effects and dependent type theories is a topic that has been explored quite a bit, see for instance [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02594), [2](https://www.xn--pdrot-bsa.fr/articles/dcbpv.pdf), [3](https://www.xn--pdrot-bsa.fr/articles/exceptional.pdf)]. I draw attention to the [fire triangle](https://www.xn--pdrot-bsa.fr/articles/dcbpv.pdf) paper, which explains the fundamental dilemma one faces when effects and dependent type theory meet.

The immediate idea one has is to express computational effects as a monad $T$, a la Eugenio Moggi. We may also split the monad $T$ into an adjunction $F \dashv U$ with $F : \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{C}$ and $U : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{V}$. We think of $\mathcal{V}$ as *value types* whose elements are values (“inert data”) and of $\mathcal{C}$ as *computation types* whose elements are computations (“active code“). This approach is known as call-by-push-value [[4](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-0954-6)].

In programming syntax the unit of the adjunction is written as `return`, and composition in the Kleisli category of the monad with the `do` notation.

When computational effects are represented as algebraic operations of an equational theory $\mathcal{E}$, the obvious adjunction $F_\mathcal{E} \dashv U_\mathcal{E}$ is the one induced by the free algebra construction. Languages that use this approach typically use the notation $A ! \mathcal{E}$ for the computation type $F_\mathcal{E}(A)$, and call the algebraic theory $\mathcal{E}$ “effect information“ or “dirt“. (In contrast, a value type $A$ is “pure” because its elements are values, free of effects.) Quite often $\mathcal{E}$ is just a signature, i.e., it has no equational axioms, because those are difficult or impossible to type check algorithmically.

##### General recursion

Let us apply the above idea to incorporating general recursion into type theory in a safe manner. We equip type theory with a monad $T$ whose purpose is to indicate the possibility of divergence. The elements of $T(A)$ are referred to as “(possibly divergent) computation”.
Next, we introduce general recursion operator
$$\frac{x : A \vdash e : T A}{\vdash \mathsf{fix}_A(x . e) : T A}$$
and the equation
$$\mathsf{fix}_A (x . e) \equiv \mathsf{do} \, \{ x {\leftarrow} \mathsf{fix}_A (x . e) \,;\, e \}.$$
Note that $\mathsf{fix}_A(x . e)$ lands in $T A$. To actually extract the result from $T A$ we need passage back to $A$. How exactly this is accomplished depends on the particularities of $T$, see for instance the [delay monad](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-54458-7_31).

##### $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$?

Type theories with $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$ are perfectly good and intersting, and they play a role in programming language theory, but cannot easily be used propositions-as-types style because $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$ entails inhabitation of every type. One can of course set up some barriers, such as a two-level type theory with logic sitting on top of the “$\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$” layer – which kind of misses the point of propositions-as-types.

Perhaps there's one remark I can make that isn't completely devoid of content. In a type theory a la Coq, we can freely pretend to have $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$, and the system generates a set of constraints on universe indices that must be satisfied. But this reminds one of a computation situated in a “context” – to be understood more generally than “typing context”. And this has been studied under the name **coeffects**, see for instance [[5](http://tomasp.net/academic/papers/structural/), [6](https://doi.org/10.1145/2692915.2628160)]. The idea is that a computation runs in an envirornment which has certain *capabilities* (variables, memory layout, communication channels, etc.). A coeffect system describes the capabilities and we can either compute the capabilities required by a program, or check whether a program fits available capabilities. I can well imagine that one could describe "universe capabilities" in this way. In a way Coq does this by computing the universe constraints, and there could be a way of exposing them explicitly in type theory using coeffects.

Comment: Thanks!  I had found most of this already (except for coeffects, which now I need to go read about!), but it's nice to have it laid out so I know I'm not missing something.  Do I understand correctly that CBPV solves the "fire triangle" problem by restricting effects to occur in computations whereas dependent elimination happens only on values?

Comment: Someone pleaase summon @pierre-marie-pédrot, I am just going to say something dumb about the fire triangle.

Comment: Indeed, dependent elimination is restricted to values. But you also need a way to evaluate value-returning computations while remembering the evaluation in the type, otherwise you would get a fairly boring system without any type-dependency on computations. That's the rôle of the dependent let.

Comment: I find it easier to understand what is going on in call-by-name, since this is the normal state of affairs in MLTT. In this case, the one difference introduced by effects is the restriction that the return predicates of eliminators must be *linear*, i.e. in some sense they must commute with effects. This might seem a bit counter-intuitive when I claimed above that dependent matches must be restricted to values, but this is what you get from the call-by-name embedding into CBPV.

Comment: Linearity is precisely ensuring that the predicate does not treat computations differently from values. A prime example of a linear predicate  → □ is something like λb. if b then True else False, i.e. a function that evaluates its argument once and for all before proceeding with the rest of the computation.

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot, thanks for dropping by. So have you ever heard anyone talking about $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$ as a computational effect? What would that mean?

Comment: I don't really see how Type : Type can be seen as an effect, at least in my intuitive understanding. AFAIK it's not even sufficient to write real fixpoints. Conversely, the idea from the other thread to encode it with guarded types aka the glorified fuel trick does not provide enough equations, and similarly for the reader monad. If the resizing axiom were an hProp we could add it as an "innocuous" effect through sheafification, though. I am not expert enough to know whether localization à la Rijke-Shulman-Spitters would allow to implement it without destroying computation.

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot I do not think we can "force" this axiom in the sense of a localization. However, could you link to the thread about the fuel trick? I have recently been thinking about a guarded version of the classic domain theoretic model of Type-in-Type, but I was curious to hear if others were thinking about this.